# Past Perfect vs Past Simple in "We [had] lived in Cracow for ten years before we moved to Hong Kong."

Tags: past-perfect, past-simple

We had lived in Cracow for ten years before we moved to Hong Kong.

OR

We lived in Cracow for ten years before we moved to Hong Kong.

In my opinion Past Perfect is more suitable here as the first part is emphasising the result of some process (for 10 years) before some time reference in the past(moved to HK).
But the book says Past Simple is correct here. I'm a bit confused. I'm not a NES, so maybe someone can clarify this for me please.

Comment: You might use the first one when talking about the time just after the move to **Hong Kong**, and the second when simply listing all the places where you have lived without any particular emphasis.

Answer (score 1):

Both are acceptable. The past simple is sufficient (and preferred) as the sequence of events is obvious.